# Exposed Filter not shown in view which has a Custom Filter Handler

Tags: views

I have a view and I programmatically created a filter for this view. (I pasted the code below).

This filter works fine but I had **other Exposed Filter** created inside the view (created by clicking add filter in the view).

Now the filter added programmatically is working fine but the other one is not shown at all.

If I disable the filter added programmatically then the other one is shown correctly. So the problem is in the code I guess.

I need both filter working together.

here is the code which adds the filter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function vouchers_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {

   if ($view->name == 'vouchers') {
    $info = array(
      'table' => 'field_data_field_labpoints',
      'field' => 'field_labpoints_value', // name of value field in that table.
      'value' => array('value' => userpoints_get_current_points()), // dynamic part.
      'operator' => '<',
      'id' => 'field_data_field_labpoints_vouchers', // unique id.
      'group' => 100, // new group.
    );
    $handler = views_get_handler($info['table'], $info['field'], 'filter');

    $handler->init($view, $info);
    $view->display_handler->handlers['filter'][$info['id']] = &$handler;

    unset($handler);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this something you could do via a contextual filter (argument) and set in code? That way you wouldn't be interfering with the normal filter handlers and could do this programmatically.

Comment: I think that adding the filter as a contextual filter would be a good choise.

Comment: @CharlieS I just found a solution based in your comment. Do you mind to move your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by adding a contextual filter, previously called an argument in D6 Views. You can set contextual filters / arguments in code when you [embed a view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7). So, you could add a contextual filter for field_labpoints (not sure what kind of field this is) and pass along the argument you want to filter for when you embed the View in a `.tpl` file or a panel or whatever:

```
print views_embed_view('my_view_name', 'block_1', $labpoints_value);
```

This allows you to make the View more dynamic without tinkering with the existing filters.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add your custom filter in a `hook_views_query_alter`? This way you'd be sure there's no conflict...